# Sending C-Struct with bytes of NData

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, struct, gamekit

I try to send an NSArray via GameKit in form of a C Struct, the struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
Message message;
unsigned int numBytes;
Byte* bytes;
} MessageBlock;
```

Here I try to get the bytes of the array and put them into the bytes variable:

```
- (void)sendBlock:(NSMutableArray*)arrayBlocks {
MessageBlock messageBlock;
messageBlock.message.messageType = kMessageTypeBlock;

NSData* arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayBlocks];
messageBlock.numBytes = sizeof(arrayData);
[arrayData getBytes:&messageBlock.bytes length:messageBlock.numBytes];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&messageBlock
                              length:sizeof(MessageBlock)];
[self sendData:data];
```

}

Soo sending works, but when I try to retrieve the array like this:

```
else if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeBlock)
{
    MessageBlock *messageBlock = (MessageBlock*)[data bytes];

    NSMutableArray* arrayBlocks = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:messageBlock->bytes length:messageBlock->numBytes]];
    [self.delegate insertBlock:arrayBlocks];
}
```

The code breaks with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. My guess: I am just sending pointers and not the actual bytes :/
So my question: How do I get the bytes of NSData into the bytes variable of the struct?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `sizeof(arrayData)` gives you the size of an `NSData *` pointer, you should do `arrayData.length`.

Comment: Then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try sending :/

Comment: That's why you're not sending the `messageBlock.bytes`, what you send is `[NSData dataWithBytes:&messageBlock length:sizeof(MessageBlock)];` that is only the `MessageBlock` structure. You should look into a C network programming tutorial and understand how to define a protocol to pass the structure with all its data.